# How to add the values in dictionary with same keys

Tags: python, dictionary

How to add the values with same keys. Is there any hack can do at the line like `sum(int(v)))`

```
m = {'Rash': 1, 'Manjeet': 1, 'Akash': 3}, {'Rash': 3, 'Manjeet': 4, 'Akash': 4}
l = []
for i in m:
    #print (i)
    for j in i.items():
        l.append(j)
from collections import defaultdict
f = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in l:
    f[k].append(int(v)) #hack
for i,j in f.items():
    print (i,sum(j))
```

My out

```
Rash 4
Manjeet 5
Akash 7
```

My expected out

```
{'Rash': 4, 'Manjeet': 5, 'Akash': 7}
```

Comment: What's the *problem* with what you've posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for a simpler approach:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for d in m:
    c += d

print(c)
# Counter({'Akash': 7, 'Manjeet': 5, 'Rash': 4})
```

---

Or using `defaultdict`:

```
out = defaultdict(int)
for d in m:
    for k,v in d.items():
        out[k] += v

print(out)
# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Rash': 4, 'Manjeet': 5, 'Akash': 7})
```